# Firebase analytics sampling limits

Tags: google-analytics, firebase, firebase-analytics

If the data set exceeds a particular value, Google analytics shows sampled results on the dashboard. The limits beyond which data is sampled (>250k sessions, >50k rows, etc.) is given here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042498?hl=en&ref_topic=2601030

What about firebase analytics? Does it sample data in the same way for generating reports? Are the sampling limits same as those for google analytics given in the link above?

Comment: They say there is just no limits and sampling data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Analytics doesn't sample the data for the reports. You can link your Firebase account to BigQuery and export the raw data if you like as well.

Answer (score 2):

Manoj: All of Firebase Analytics reports are backed by aggregates. So the good news is that you do not have to worry about sampling when viewing the reports.